# Iterating through dictionaries to display values that don't exceed a number

Tags: python-2.7, dictionary

The API-called data looks like the contents at the bottom.

```
APIkey = 'PB36zotwgisM02kED1vWwvf7BklqCObDGVoyssVE'
APIUrl='https://api.data.gov/regulations/v3/'
docketID=raw_input("Enter Docket ID") => EPA-HQ-OAR-2011-0028
url=APIUrl+'docket.json?api_key='+APIkey+'&docketId='+docketID
response = json.load(urlopen(url))
Max=150
```

I want to iterate through them like so:
Iterate through the dictionary and print the `docketID`, `title` and `numberOfComments` if the `numberOfComments` is smaller than 150.

```
​for dic in response:
    if type(dic) is dict:
        if 'numberOfComments'<Max:
            content={
               'docketID':docketID,
               'title': dic['title'],
               'numberOfComments': item['numberOfComments']        
            }

print content
```

> error: name 'content' is not defined

Can someone help make this code work? :(

---

```
response={u'publicationPeriod': {u'value': u'Fall 2012', u'label': u'Publication Period'}, u'timeTables': [{u'action': u'NPRM', u'actionQualifier': u'NPRM', u'date': u'01/10/2012', u'frCitation': u'77 FR 1434'}, {u'action': u'Final Rule', u'actionQualifier': u'Final Rule', u'date': u'08/13/2012', u'frCitation': u'77 FR 48072'}], u'impactsAndEffects': u'None', u'rin': u'2060-AQ70', u'agendaStageOfRulemaking': {u'value': u'Completed Action', u'label': u'Agenda Stage of Rulemaking'}, u'keywords': {u'value': u'CBI, Confidentiality', u'label': u'Keyword(s)'}, u'legalAuthorities': {u'value': u'42 USC 7401 et seq', u'label': u'Legal Authorities'}, u'energyEffects': {u'value': u'No', u'label': u'Energy Effects'}, u'title': u'Proposed Confidentiality Determinations for Eight Subparts of the Mandatory Greenhouse Gas Reporting Rule', u'generic': {u'value': u'HQ-OAR', u'label': u'Location'}, u'internationalImpacts': {u'value': u'No', u'label': u'International Impacts'}, u'agency': u'Environmental Protection Agency', u'smallEntitiesAffected': {u'value': u'No', u'label': u'Small Entities Affected'}, u'ruleMakingStage': u'Completed', u'priority': u'Substantive, Nonsignificant', u'requiresRegulatoryFlexibilityAnalysis': {u'value': u'No', u'label': u'Requires Regulatory Flexibility Analysis'}, u'legalDeadlines': {u'value': u'None', u'label': u'Legal Deadlines'}, u'cfrCitation': u'40 CFR 98', u'federalismImplications': {u'value': u'No', u'label': u'Federalism Implications'}, u'majorRule': {u'value': u'No', u'label': u'Major Rule'}, u'agencyAcronym': u'EPA', u'docketId': u'EPA-HQ-OAR-2011-0028', u'unfundedMandates': {u'value': u'No', u'label': u'Unfunded Mandates'}, u'numberOfComments': 22, u'shortTitle': {u'value': u'Confidentiality Determinations for Eight Subparts of the GHGRP', u'label': u'Short Title'}, u'includedInRegulatoryPlan': {u'value': u'No', u'label': u'Included in Regulatory Plan'}, u'type': {u'value': u'Rulemaking', u'label': u'Type'}, u'governmentLevelsAffected': {u'value': u'Federal', u'label': u'Government Levels Affected'}, u'docketAbstract': u'This action finalized confidentiality determinations for certain data elements in nine subparts under the Mandatory Greenhouse Gas Reporting Rule. In addition, EPA is finalizing amendments to subpart A to defer the reporting deadline of certain data elements in subparts FF and TT until 2013 and to defer the reporting deadline of certain data elements in subpart W until 2015. Lastly, the EPA is finalizing amendments to subpart I regarding the calculation and reporting of emissions from facilities that use best available monitoring methods. This action does not include final confidentiality determinations for data elements in the "Inputs to Emission Equations" data category.', u'contact': [{u'city': u'Washington', u'fax': u'202 343-2202', u'zip': u'20460', u'agencyName': u'DEFAULT', u'firstName': u'Lisa', u'lastName': u'Bacanskas', u'agency': u'AR', u'streetAddress': u'6207J, Washington, DC 20460', u'phone': u'202 343-9758', u'state': u'DC', u'emailAddress': u'Bacanskas.Lisa@epamail.epa.gov'}, {u'city': u'Washington', u'fax': u'202 343-2359', u'zip': u'20460', u'agencyName': u'DEFAULT', u'firstName': u'Barbora', u'lastName': u'Master', u'agency': u'AR', u'streetAddress': u'6207J, Washington, DC 20460', u'phone': u'202 343-9899', u'state': u'DC', u'emailAddress': u'master.barbora@epamail.epa.gov'}]}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You declare `content` inside the if-clause and it is therefore not defined, if the `if` clause does not evaluate to `true`. Simply put the `print` inside the `if` clause:

```
​for dic in response:
    if item['numberOfComments'] < Max:
        content={
            'docketID':docketID,
            'title': dic['title'],
            'numberOfComments': item['numberOfComments']
        }        
        print content
```

Comment: lol I found that all of my comments were irrelevant and erased them. It got solved with 
`for key, value in response.items(): if type(value)==int: print value`
, bc ['numberOfComments'] happens to be the only _int_ in the dictionary. Thank you!